# PostgreSQL: Non-null replacements in data subsets

Tags: postgresql, interpolation

**EDIT My bad, called timestamp 'date'...**

Our data table is comprised of a timestamp, value, and delta column. The delta is the number of minutes since the last non-null reading.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("ts" timestamp with time zone, "value" numeric, "delta" int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ("ts", "value", "delta")
VALUES
    ('2019-09-09 12:01:00', 3.5, NULL),
    ('2019-09-09 12:02:00', 3.2, 1),
    ('2019-09-09 12:03:00', NULL, 1),
    ('2019-09-09 12:04:00', 2.9, 2),
    ('2019-09-09 12:05:00', NULL, 1),
    ('2019-09-09 12:06:00', 3.0, 2),
    ('2019-09-09 12:07:00', NULL, 1),
    ('2019-09-09 12:08:00', NULL, 2),
    ('2019-09-09 12:09:00', NULL, 3),
    ('2019-09-09 12:10:00', NULL, 4),
    ('2019-09-09 12:11:00', 3.2, 5),
    ('2019-09-09 12:12:00', NULL, 1)
;
SELECT ts,
       value,
       delta,
  FROM table

+---------------------+-------+-------+
| ts                  | value | delta |
+---------------------+-------+-------+
| 2019-09-09 12:01:00 | 3.5   | 1     |
| 2019-09-09 12:02:00 | 3.2   | 1     |
| 2019-09-09 12:03:00 |       | 1     |
| 2019-09-09 12:04:00 | 2.9   | 2     |
| 2019-09-09 12:05:00 |       | 1     |
| 2019-09-09 12:06:00 | 3.0   | 2     |
| 2019-09-09 12:07:00 |       | 1     |
| 2019-09-09 12:08:00 |       | 2     |
| 2019-09-09 12:09:00 |       | 3     |
| 2019-09-09 12:10:00 |       | 4     |
| 2019-09-09 12:11:00 | 3.2   | 5     |
| 2019-09-09 12:12:00 |       | 1     |
+---------------------+-------+-------+
```

Given a subset of the data, how can we replace null values with the last non-null value **IF that replacement value has not already been selected**:

```
SELECT ts,
       value,
       delta,
  FROM table
 WHERE (/* expression giving us an arbitrary distribution of rows */)

+---------------------+-------+-------+
| ts                  | value | delta |
+---------------------+-------+-------+
| 2019-09-09 12:01:00 | 3.5   |       |
| 2019-09-09 12:03:00 |       | 1     |
| 2019-09-09 12:05:00 |       | 1     |
| 2019-09-09 12:07:00 |       | 1     |
| 2019-09-09 12:09:00 |       | 3     |
| 2019-09-09 12:11:00 | 3.2   | 5     |
+---------------------+-------+-------+
```

We want:

```
+---------------------+-------+-------+
| ts                  | value | delta |
+---------------------+-------+-------+
| 2019-09-09 12:01:00 | 3.5   |       |
| 2019-09-09 12:03:00 | 3.2   | 1     |
| 2019-09-09 12:05:00 | 2.9   | 1     |
| 2019-09-09 12:07:00 | 3.0   | 1     |
| 2019-09-09 12:09:00 |       | 3     |<- an actual null
| 2019-09-09 12:11:00 | 3.2   | 5     |
+---------------------+-------+-------+
```

The distribution of rows is odd in this case; however, this is arbitrary. We cannot use a perceived pattern in date frequency in determining when and if to use last non-null values.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/48297/4/0)

**What We've Tried So Far**

As a first step, carry forward all last values.

```
WITH seq AS (
  SELECT ts,
         value,
         delta,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date) AS row_no,
         COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_count
    FROM Table1
 ),
 val AS (
   SELECT ts,
          value,
          value_p,
          first_value(value) over (partition by value_p order by date),
          delta,
          row_no,
          total_count
     FROM (
       SELECT ts,
              value,
              delta,
              row_no,
              total_count,
              sum(case when value is null then 0 else 1 end) over
                (order by date) as value_p
         FROM seq
     ORDER BY ts
       ) as a
)
SELECT ts,
       delta,
       value,
       case when value is null then first_value else value 
       end as cf
  FROM val

|                  ts |  delta |  value |  cf |
|---------------------|--------|--------|-----|
| 2019-09-09 12:01:00 | (null) |    3.5 | 3.5 |
| 2019-09-09 12:02:00 |      1 |    3.2 | 3.2 |
| 2019-09-09 12:03:00 |      1 | (null) | 3.2 |
| 2019-09-09 12:04:00 |      2 |    2.9 | 2.9 |
| 2019-09-09 12:05:00 |      1 | (null) | 2.9 |
| 2019-09-09 12:06:00 |      2 |      3 |   3 |
| 2019-09-09 12:07:00 |      1 | (null) |   3 |
| 2019-09-09 12:08:00 |      2 | (null) |   3 |
| 2019-09-09 12:09:00 |      3 | (null) |   3 |
| 2019-09-09 12:10:00 |      4 | (null) |   3 |
| 2019-09-09 12:11:00 |      5 |    3.2 | 3.2 |
| 2019-09-09 12:12:00 |      1 | (null) | 3.2 |
```

When we distribute the rows for the data subset, we now have both the value and how many rows back that value came from. What we can't figure out is how to determine whether or not to carry a value forward or leave as null when we generate the subset via the WHERE.

Bonus points awarded if the solution doesn't require a predefined delta column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea to use `sum(case when value is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by date) as value_p` was a good one.  This sorts the values into groups with the same value_p.

From there, if you treat `date` as an actual timestamp, you can group the dates together using tsrange(min(date), max(date), '[]').  Make sure the ends of the range are inclusive to capture the rows where the beginning and end of the group is the same time.

Then, just join to your test dates using the contained by operator.

```
WITH test_dates(test_date) as (VALUES 
        ('2019-09-09 12:01:00'::timestamp),
        ('2019-09-09 12:03:00'),
        ('2019-09-09 12:05:00'),
        ('2019-09-09 12:07:00'),
        ('2019-09-09 12:09:00'),
        ('2019-09-09 12:11:00')
), value_ranges AS (
    SELECT tsrange(min(date)::timestamp, max(date)::timestamp, '[]') as sample_range, 
       max(value) as value, -- There's only one non-null value, this could be min
       value_p
    FROM (
       SELECT date,
       value,
       sum(case when value is null then 0 else 1 end) over
            (order by date) as value_p
       FROM table1
    ) sub 
    GROUP BY value_p
)
SELECT test_date, 
       CASE WHEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY value_p ORDER BY test_date) = 1 THEN value 
       ELSE null END  -- Only the first row of the group is non-null
FROM test_dates
JOIN value_ranges on test_date <@ sample_range
;
```

There's no need for the delta column.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a56f3/84)

Comment: Heady mind bending stuff. Works great for a small dataset, but is expensive as the data grows e.g. pulling 500 rows out of 25,000 = 1.5 sec. This after replacing tsrange with a faster min(date),max(date), and JOIN ... ON test_date >= min AND <= max. Any advice to further optimize?

Comment: Yes, joining on those will be faster, unless you store the dates as actual timestamps, which I would recommend.  All that aggregation will definitely be expensive, but to recommend any further optimizations, we'd have to see the output of explain analyze (in a new question).

Comment: Dates are actually timestamps. My initial edit and fiddle was incorrectly set to 'date' as varchar...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: Realized I was pulling entries after the sample reference point when I should have been pulling the entries before. Fixed.**

Given your table and assuming that you wanted a timestamptz, not a date, this will give you what you want. Just change the `minutes_between_intervals` column in the first table expression to spread the samples.

I've left the CTEs somewhat more verbose than they need to be to help readability.

```
WITH with_offsets AS (

  -- First add in some metadata about how many minutes have elapsed since you
  -- started sampling along with a constant for the sampling interval.

  SELECT
    2 AS minutes_between_intervals, -- This is how often you're sampling
    date,
    value,
    delta,
    extract(minute FROM date - (min(date) OVER (ORDER BY date)))::integer AS minutes_offset
  FROM Table1

), with_groups AS (

  -- Add grouping, setting the sample entries as reference points and the
  -- entries leading up to it as part of its group.

  SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN minutes_offset % minutes_between_intervals = 0 THEN minutes_offset
         ELSE minutes_offset + (minutes_between_intervals - (minutes_offset % minutes_between_intervals))
    END AS sample_group,
    minutes_offset % minutes_between_intervals = 0 AS is_sample_boundary
  FROM with_offsets

), with_arrays AS (

  -- Then aggregate them into arrays. The values array has all NULLs
  -- removed. The groups with sample entries are marked.

  SELECT
    array_agg(date) AS dates,
    array_agg(value) FILTER (WHERE value IS NOT NULL) AS values,
    array_agg(delta) AS deltas,
    bool_or(is_sample_boundary) AS has_complete_sample
  FROM with_groups
  GROUP BY sample_group
)

-- Now take the last entry from each array, which will be the sample date,
-- the last recorded value, and the last recorded sample delta.

SELECT
  dates[array_upper(dates, 1)] AS date,
  values[array_upper(values, 1)] AS value,
  deltas[array_upper(deltas, 1)] AS delta
FROM with_arrays
WHERE has_complete_sample;
```

Comment: We don't know beforehand how the sampling ends up. It's variable based on the size of the original pool of data, and may not be in even increments.